# Creating a Month Dropdown in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

This method seems stupid and a bit heavy; is there a more optimal way of creating the same thing (its for an MVC View Dropdown)

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> getMonthListDD
{
    get
    {
        var dDur = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "January"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Febuary"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "March"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "April"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(5, "May"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(6, "June"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(7, "July"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(8, "August"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(9, "September"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(10, "October"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(11, "November"));
        dDur.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(12, "December"));

        return dDur;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In your view model you could have a `Months` property:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
{
    get 
    {
        return DateTimeFormatInfo
               .InvariantInfo
               .MonthNames
               .Select((monthName, index) => new SelectListItem
               {
                   Value = (index + 1).ToString(),
                   Text = monthName
               });
    }
}
```

which could be directly bound to a `DropDownListFor`:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedMonth, Model.Months) %>
```

Comment: Wow so many ways to skin the same rabbit; But I like this one most as it 'feels' clean. I'll probably ram them all into a bulk load and see which ones fastest :op

Comment: The only downside to this approach as written is that there's 13 month entries in MonthNames (January -> December plus a "blank" month).  This might be OK for your UI to have the blank box, but if you want to have a custom selector label then you need to account for that by trimming it off.

Comment: if you want to do what @Paul mentioned, you can simply add `.Where(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m))` right before the Select statement

Comment: I like to set the property in the constructor so that every time you call the property it isn't invoking the code in the getter over and over.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov 
 error CS1061: 'project.Models.ModelName' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedMonth' and no extension method 'SelectedMonth' accepting a first argument of type 'project.Models.ModelName' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any suggestions????

Answer (score 7):

Simplicity is gold, so in your View:

```
<select id="month">
    @for (Int16 i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        <option value="@i">@DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames[i]</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on darins simple and elegant reply, i thought I'd share the little helper method that i refactored as a result of seeing this:

```
public static string ComboDaysOfWeek(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, string selectedValue)
{
    var newitems = DateTimeFormatInfo
        .InvariantInfo
        .DayNames
        .Select((dayName, index) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = (index + 1).ToString(),
            Text = dayName,
            Selected = (selectedValue == (index + 1).ToString())
        });

    var result = helper.DropDownList(id, newitems).ToHtmlString();
    return result;
}
```

usage:

```
<%= Html.ComboDaysOfWeek("ActivityStartDay", Model.ActivityStartDay)%>
```

**[edit]** - this is in MVC2, therefore the .ToHtmlString() is added to the helper.DropDownList() method.

Comment: ... sorted!! :) - you obvioulsy could take this approach with your month dropdown as well, rather than attaching it to your model as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

For Month.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x) }), "Select Month", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For Year.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() }), "Select Year", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dDur = new Dictionary<int, string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    dDur.Add(i, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i));
}

return dDur;
```

Remember and add a using directive for `System.Globalization` at the top of your class.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
       get
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select Month", Value = "0" });
            list.AddRange(DateTimeFormatInfo
                  .InvariantInfo
                  .MonthNames
                  .Where(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
                  .Select((monthName, index) => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = (index + 1).ToString(),
                      Text = monthName
                  }).ToList());

            return list;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind it straight to your dropdown

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    MonthDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`

```
for(int i=1; i<=12; i++)
    myDict.Add(i, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i));
```